# (MVC 3 Razor) - Easier way to loop through 3 column div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

At the moment I'm using the following code in my CSHTML:

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.Traders)
{
    if ((i++ % 3) == 0) {
        if (i != 1) {
            @:</div>
        }
        @:<div class="row">
    }

    @:<div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>@item.Title</strong></h3><p>@item.Description</p><code>&lt;div class=&quot;panel pick&quot;&gt;</code></div></div>
}

@if (i != 0) {
    @:</div>
}
```

This outputs the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>Title</strong></h3><p>Description</p><code>code</code></div></div>
    <div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>Title</strong></h3><p>Description</p><code>code</code></div></div>
    <div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>Title</strong></h3><p>Description</p><code>code</code></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>Bobby</strong></h3><p>Bobby bobby bobby</p><code>&lt;div class=&quot;panel pick&quot;&gt;</code></div></div>
    <!-- Add missing divs if there's less than 3 (there always needs to be 3 divs inside a div row). In this case it's 2 that are missing -->
    <div class="four column"></div> <!-- my code does not render these -->
    <div class="four column"></div> <!-- my code does not render these -->
</div>
```

My question is whether there's an easier way to achieve what I'm doing within my view and to ensure that it adds the missing divs if there's less than 3 in a row.

Comment: what data you want to show from Traders?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh It's irrelevant, I only want a better way to render the already working HTML result.

Comment: just added an answer. try that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Group traders in batch of 3 items, Try this:

```
@{

    var g = Model.Traders.GroupBy(r => Model.Traders.IndexOf(r) / 3).ToList();
}

@foreach (var parentItem in g)
{ 
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in parentItem)
        { 
           <div class="four column"><div class="panel new"><h3 class="dotted"><strong>@item.Title</strong></h3><p>@item.Description</p><code>&lt;div class=&quot;panel pick&quot;&gt;</code></div></div>


        }


    @for (int i = parentItem.Count(); i < 3; i++)
    { 
        <div class="four column"></div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Regards.

Comment: IndexOf is a method expose by a object implements IList. Traders data type must be array.. try Model.Traders.ToList().IndexOf(r)

Comment: even you can use Array.IndexOf(Model.Traders,r)

Comment: This works, however it doesn't add the empty divs if there are less than 3 results. `<div class="four column"></div>`

Comment: even the code you shared won't create empty divs with class="four columns". but if this is the case check the code i just added

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that. Your code works perfectly now. Thanks.